# Update state from deeply nested component without re-rendering parents

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-context, react-state-management

[image: input and map inside content, content inside page, page and button inside layout]

I have a form page structured more or less as follows:

```
<Layout>
  <Page>
    <Content>
      <Input />
      <Map />
    </Content>
  </Page>
  <Button />
</Layout>
```

The Map component should only be rendered once, as there is an animation that is triggered on render. That means that Content, Page and Layout should not re-render at all.

The Button inside Layout should be disabled when the Input is empty. The value of the Input is not controlled by Content, as a state change would cause a re-render of the Map.

I've tried a few different things (using refs, useImperativeHandle, etc) but none of the solutions feel very clean to me. What's the best way to go about connecting the state of the Input to the state of the Button, without changing the state of Layout, Page or Content? Keep in mind that this is a fairly small project and the codebase uses "modern" React practices (e.g. hooks), and doesn't have global state management like Redux, MobX, etc.

Comment: This is now possible using [Signals](https://preactjs.com/blog/introducing-signals/), developed by the Preact team. If you're familiar with Vue's Composition API, Signals work exactly like refs. [Click here for an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-signals-to-share-state-and-avoid-re-renders-z8kmdw).

Comment: Another solution would be [zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand), which is [about half the size](https://bundlephobia.com/package/zustand@4.3.2) of [@preact/signals-react](https://bundlephobia.com/package/@preact/signals-react@1.2.2) and arguably more powerful. [Click here for an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-zustand-to-share-state-and-avoid-re-renders-5uegb3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example ([click here to play with it](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-mestorf-5b68x)) that avoids re-render of `Map`. However, it re-renders other components because I pass `children` around. But if map is the heaviest, that should do the trick. To avoid rendering of other components you need to get rid of `children` prop but that most probably means you will need redux. You can also try to use context but I never worked with it so idk how it would affect rendering in general

```
import React, { useState, useRef, memo } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const GenericComponent = memo(
  ({ name = "GenericComponent", className, children }) => {
    const counter = useRef(0);
    counter.current += 1;

    return (
      <div className={"GenericComponent " + className}>
        <div className="Counter">
          {name} rendered {counter.current} times
        </div>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
);

const Layout = memo(({ children }) => {
  return (
    <GenericComponent name="Layout" className="Layout">
      {children}
    </GenericComponent>
  );
});

const Page = memo(({ children }) => {
  return (
    <GenericComponent name="Page" className="Page">
      {children}
    </GenericComponent>
  );
});

const Content = memo(({ children }) => {
  return (
    <GenericComponent name="Content" className="Content">
      {children}
    </GenericComponent>
  );
});

const Map = memo(({ children }) => {
  return (
    <GenericComponent name="Map" className="Map">
      {children}
    </GenericComponent>
  );
});

const Input = ({ value, setValue }) => {
  const onChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setValue(value);
  };
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={typeof value === "string" ? value : ""}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  );
};

const Button = ({ disabled = false }) => {
  return (
    <button type="button" disabled={disabled}>
      Button
    </button>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>SO Q#60060672</h1>

      <Layout>
        <Page>
          <Content>
            <Input value={value} setValue={setValue} />
            <Map />
          </Content>
        </Page>
        <Button disabled={value === ""} />
      </Layout>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Update

Below is [version](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-liskov-mupwm) with context that does not re-render components except input and button:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, memo, useContext } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const ValueContext = React.createContext({
  value: "",
  setValue: () => {}
});

const Layout = memo(() => {
  const counter = useRef(0);
  counter.current += 1;

  return (
    <div className="GenericComponent">
      <div className="Counter">Layout rendered {counter.current} times</div>
      <Page />
      <Button />
    </div>
  );
});

const Page = memo(() => {
  const counter = useRef(0);
  counter.current += 1;

  return (
    <div className="GenericComponent">
      <div className="Counter">Page rendered {counter.current} times</div>
      <Content />
    </div>
  );
});

const Content = memo(() => {
  const counter = useRef(0);
  counter.current += 1;

  return (
    <div className="GenericComponent">
      <div className="Counter">Content rendered {counter.current} times</div>
      <Input />
      <Map />
    </div>
  );
});

const Map = memo(() => {
  const counter = useRef(0);
  counter.current += 1;

  return (
    <div className="GenericComponent">
      <div className="Counter">Map rendered {counter.current} times</div>
    </div>
  );
});

const Input = () => {
  const { value, setValue } = useContext(ValueContext);

  const onChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setValue(value);
  };

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={typeof value === "string" ? value : ""}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  );
};

const Button = () => {
  const { value } = useContext(ValueContext);

  return (
    <button type="button" disabled={value === ""}>
      Button
    </button>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>SO Q#60060672, method 2</h1>

      <p>
        Type something into input below to see how rendering counters{" "}
        <s>update</s> stay the same
      </p>

      <ValueContext.Provider value={{ value, setValue }}>
        <Layout />
      </ValueContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Solutions rely on using `memo` to avoid rendering when parent re-renders and minimizing amount of properties passed to components. Ref's are used only for render counters

Comment: Nice work, I like your render counter solution too.

Comment: The second solution is exactly what I was looking for. I totally forgot about React.memo!

Comment: This answer had a big impact on me, thank you for sharing!

Comment: Now there's an even cleaner solution using [Signals](https://preactjs.com/blog/introducing-signals/), developed by the Preact team. If you're familiar with Vue's Composition API, Signals work exactly like refs. [Click here for an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-signals-to-share-state-and-avoid-re-renders-z8kmdw).

Answer (score 1):

I have a sure way to solve it, but a little more complicated.
Use createContext and useContext to transfer data from layout to input. This way you can use a global state without using Redux. (redux also uses context by the way to distribute its data). Using context you can prevent property change in all the component between Layout and Imput.

I have a second easier option, but I'm not sure it works in this case. You can wrap Map to React.memo to prevent render if its property is not changed. It's quick to try and it may work.

**UPDATE**

I tried out React.memo on Map component. I modified Gennady's example. And it works just fine without context. You just pass the value and setValue to all component down the chain. You can pass all property easy like: `<Content {...props} />` This is the easiest solution.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, memo } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Layout = props => {
  const counter = useRef(0);
  counter.current += 1;

  return (
    <div className="GenericComponent">
      <div className="Counter">Layout rendered {counter.current} times</div>
      <Page {...props} />
      <Button {...props} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Page = props => {
  const counter = useRef(0);
  counter.current += 1;

  return (
    <div className="GenericComponent">
      <div className="Counter">Page rendered {counter.current} times</div>
      <Content {...props} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Content = props => {
  const counter = useRef(0);
  counter.current += 1;

  return (
    <div className="GenericComponent">
      <div className="Counter">Content rendered {counter.current} times</div>
      <Input {...props} />
      <Map />
    </div>
  );
};

const Map = memo(() => {
  const counter = useRef(0);
  counter.current += 1;

  return (
    <div className="GenericComponent">
      <div className="Counter">Map rendered {counter.current} times</div>
    </div>
  );
});

const Input = ({ value, setValue }) => {
  const counter = useRef(0);
  counter.current += 1;

  const onChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setValue(value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      Input rendedred {counter.current} times{" "}
      <input
        type="text"
        value={typeof value === "string" ? value : ""}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </>
  );
};

const Button = ({ value }) => {
  const counter = useRef(0);
  counter.current += 1;

  return (
    <button type="button" disabled={value === ""}>
      Button (rendered {counter.current} times)
    </button>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>SO Q#60060672, method 2</h1>

      <p>
        Type something into input below to see how rendering counters{" "}
        <s>update</s> stay the same, except for input and button
      </p>
      <Layout value={value} setValue={setValue} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-wind-wif8b